# C++ Windows Forms application icon exception

Tags: visual-studio, exception, visual-c++, icons, windows-forms-designer

I want to set an icon for my Windows Form application. My actions step by step:

1. I created an 'icon.ico' (256x256) and put it into my project folder
2. In my 'Form1.h [Design]' I chose this file using Properties
3. This code appeared in 'Form1.h'

```
void InitializeComponent(void)
{ ...
this->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^>(resources->GetObject(L"$this.Icon")));
... }
```

4. The object '$this.Icon' appeared in 'Form1.resx'
5. I rebuilt the whole project -> no errors
6. During execution the line 'this->Icon = ...' causes an exception: System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "WinForm.Form1.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "MyProject" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fb15c8c7-3ae1-48c2-89e6-b1ea61411cbb/windows-form-application-throws-exception-after-adding-an-icon?forum=vclanguage) I found numerous advices, such as remove/add icon or set some custom properties for 'Form1.resx', but none of them works for me

Answer (score 0):

Place the Icon you want to connect to your Form in the project directory.
Then replace the line above with the following:

```cpp
this->Icon = gcnew System::Drawing::Icon(L"app.ico");
```

This should neutralize the bug that Microsoft has not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just like above, change line to:

```
this->Icon = gcnew System::Drawing::Icon(L"ICON_NAME.ico");
```

You might get error/exception while opening form creator but you shouldn't lose any data.
Been there, done that :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't duplicate answers. If you have a new aspect of the question to address then please leave an answer and note that in the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **visual studio 2019** , you need to change the name of namespace in **Form1** the same as **your project name**, i did it and it works

and make sure you change it in main :

```
[STAThread]
int main() {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application::Run(gcnew your_namespace_name::Form1());
    return 0;
}
```