# (C++ WinForms VS 2022) Icon Exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms, exception, icons

When I attempt to change the icon of the form in the properties window [(this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLSRq.png), this line of code gets generated in the .h file:

```
this->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^>(resources->GetObject(L"$this.Icon")));
```

But when I try to run it, it gives me a `System.Resources.MissingManfiestResourceException` error:

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException   HResult=0x80131532
> Message=Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified
> culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure
> "Thermodynamics_Generator.Form1.resources" was correctly embedded or
> linked into assembly "thermodynamics_generator" at compile time, or
> that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
> signed.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:    at
> System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String
> fileName)    at
> System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo
> culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean
> createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
> System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
> requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents,
> StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
> System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo
> culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)    at
> System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name, CultureInfo
> culture, Boolean wrapUnmanagedMemStream)    at
> System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(String name)    at
> Thermodynamics_Generator.Form1.InitializeComponent() in
> C:\Users\my_name\source\repos\thermodynamics_generator\thermodynamics_generator\thermodynamics_generator.h:line
> 1194    at Thermodynamics_Generator.Form1..ctor() in
> C:\Users\my_name\source\repos\thermodynamics_generator\thermodynamics_generator\thermodynamics_generator.h:line
> 26    at main() in
> C:\Users\my_name\source\repos\thermodynamics_generator\thermodynamics_generator\CppCLR_WinformsProject.cpp:line
> 11

And I have tried something like this from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58417832/c-windows-forms-application-icon-exception) to do this instead:

```
this->Icon = gcnew System::Drawing::Icon(L"app.ico");
```

It works, but when ran on other computers, it just does not want to run at all (only wants to run on my computer).

I also checked the .resx file to see `$this.Icon` is there but still gives me an exception.

If there is other things I mention, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
this->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^>(resources->GetObject(L"$this.Icon")));
```

This line of code is automatically generated, where $this.Icon contains the file path, you could read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject?view=netframework-4.7.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(SYSTEM%252FSystem%253A%253AComponentModel%253A%253AComponentResourceManager%253A%253AGetObject);k(System%253A%253AComponentModel%253A%253AComponentResourceManager%253A%253AGetObject);k(MSCORLIB%252FSystem%253A%253AResources%253A%253AResourceManager%253A%253AGetObject);k(System%253A%253AResources%253A%253AResourceManager%253A%253AGetObject);k(GetObject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-C%252B%252B);k(TargetOS-Windows);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.7.2)%26rd%3Dtrue) for the `GetObject()`. And the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.resources.resourcemanager?view=netframework-4.7.2#instantiating-a-resourcemanager-object) states that

> If the appropriate resources cannot be found, the constructor call
> creates a valid ResourceManager object. However, the attempt to
> retrieve a resource throws a MissingManifestResourceException
> exception. For information about dealing with the exception, see the
> Handling MissingManifestResourceException and MissingSatelliteAssembly
> Exceptions section later in this article.

We could conclude that the program did not find your resource file. If you want to run the program on other computers, you must ensure that the icon path is consistent with your computer.

Edit:

I suggest you to check if the resource is included as a project, select `All Files` in `Solution Exploer`, then right click on the resource file and select `Include In Project`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried to change the icon on an empty form and the same error still occurred.

Comment: @softie, Hi, I updated my answer, could this help you?

Comment: I right clicked on the icon file in the Solution Explorer and it just says 'Exclude From Project' instead. And yes, I did import it via "Resource Files > Add > Resource > Icon > Import" (the icon file was in the project folder too before importing it). (also, explorer is spelled wrong, lol)

Comment: @softie, Hi, try adding the absolute path to the ioc file in `this->Icon = gcnew System::Drawing::Icon(L"app.ico");`. It is also possible that the cause of the problem is VS, I suggest you try to repair VS.

Comment: I did that, and it ran fine on my pc, had the icon and everything. But when I ran it on another machine, it just straight up refused to run, while in the process loosing its icon. As for the last part, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Oh and I also used VS 2019 and the same exact error had still occured.

Comment: @softie, Hi, if it is convenient, could you download VS2022 and install the necessary environment for testing? If that doesn't work, excluding the results we discussed above, all I can do is suggest that you report the issue to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion).

Comment: What would be the necessary environment for VS 2022? Like what would I need to install? Because currently I have installed: `Desktop development with C++`, .`NET desktop development`, `Python development`, `Mobile development with C++`, and `Game development with C++`.

Comment: @softie, Hi, this is a CLR program, so you need to install C++/CLI support. I will put this package into the answer for you to check.

Comment: Alright, I have installed the package now. After changing the icon and running it, the same error still occurs. What else is there to do now?

Comment: @softie,  Excluding the results we discussed above, I think the problem may be with VS or your computer. Suppose the computer that can run the program is A, and the other is B. What is the difference between A and B?

Comment: One of them is a laptop, and the other one is a desktop (the computer I'm writing the program in)

Comment: Opened the solution in VS 2022 on my laptop to change the icon there instead and it gives the same exception. No difference from my desktop.

Comment: Still there...?

Comment: Sorry, at present, it seems that the problem may be on your computer or VS. If the problem is on the computer, you may need to check it yourself. If the problem is on VS, since I am not an expert in VS, I could only suggest that you go to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion) and ask questions.